# i Downloaded debian iso from Debian's website but its not bootable

Tags: iso, bootable

I loaded the ISO file to poweriso or rufus but it says its not a bootable image. how can I make it bootable.

EDIT: I checked the hashes too

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't boot from `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso` it is not bootable .You need to download **the first one** `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso` as described [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) :

> initially, you will only need to download and use the first image of a set (labelled as debian-something-1 to be able to start the Debian installer and set up Debian on your computer. If there are more images available here (labelled debian-something-2, debian-something-3, etc.), they contain the extra packages that can be installed on a Debian system (as mentioned previously). They will not be bootable and are entirely optional. If you have a fast Internet connection, you're most likely better off installing any desired extra packages directly from the Debian mirrors on the Internet instead of by using these extra images.

*I have downloaded the `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso` , how to use it?*

You can add the iso to your `sources.list` to install some packages.

To know the list of package in the ISO you can download the `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.list.gz`:

```
zcat debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.list.gz
```

To add the DVD to your sources.list:

mount the iso:

```
mkdir /mnt/DVD3
mount -o loop /path/to/debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso /mnt/DVD3
```

Add an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
path/to/debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso /mnt/DVD3 iso9660 loop,ro,user,noauto   0      0
```

Then add it to your sources.list:

```
apt-cdrom -d=/mnt/DVD1 add
```

see `man apt-cdrom`

Comment: so how can we use debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso ??? I have downloaded this version and I have googled a lot but I couldn't find a way to install it ... can you help ? thanks

Comment: @Parsa See my update please.

Answer (score 0):

> i Downloaded debian iso from Debian's website

Which ISO image did you download exactly?

> rufus [...] says its not a bootable image

Sounds like you might have a corrupted or incomplete download. I'd recommend that you verify the completeness of your downloaded image. On Windows, [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) will allow you to easily view the SHA256 hash of your ISO image.

1. After you've installed HashTab, in Windows Explorer, right-click on your downloaded ISO file and select "Properties".
2. Select the "File Hashes" tab.
3. Compare the hash displayed in this dialog with the appropriate hash for your image. For example, the image I downloaded has the filename `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`. You can find reference hashes in the same location from which you obtained your ISO files.

If the hashes are different, then you will know that your download is incomplete (screenshot attached, showing matching hash values).

[image: HashTab]

If you continue to have trouble with incomplete downloads, try using BitTorrent to download your images instead of HTTP.

Comment: i checked the hashes ..... and its the same(i have provided the picture above). Thanks

Comment: i also used terminal to check sha1 and md5 but the results are same

Comment: Which version of Rufus are you using?
What is the exact error message that Rufus gives you after selecting the Debian ISO?

Comment: i'm using rufus 2.6.818 and the error is 
_This image is either non bootable , or it uses a boot or compression method that is not supported by te rufus_ 
I have also tried this iso with poweriso but it shows me non bootable in bottom left of the window.

Comment: Please see GAD3R's solution, as it is the correct one.